# when did C3P0 C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager put second authsToPools's value?

Tags: datasource, c3p0

when I read C3p0's code ,I discovered C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager class has a filed called authToPools that store user'info and ConnectionPool map.It seemds that multiple datasource will create two datasoure which have its C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager respectively. I wanna know when C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager put the second map value. Thanks for your resoultion!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. c3p0 maintains a distinct pool for each authentication, because Connections are nor interchangeable across authentications. An operation that should succeed against one Connection should fail against a one with different authentication. As long as you only use the default authentication [that is, you never call `getConnection( user, password )`] there will be only a single pool. But if you ask for Connections with multiple auths, you'll spawn multiple pools.

Comment: yeah I had get resolution maybe. I see the source code again.I discovered it will put the user's pool into the authToPool Map object when you call getConnection(user,password) and its pool doesn't exist. Thanks for your advice.